# why is my loop iterating and how do i resolve this?

Tags: java, netbeans, dice

My code is not stopping the iteration where i use the do while loop, i wanted to only iterate when the secondThrow is not the same as the firstThrow and not a number 7????? help

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Craps_callee 
{
    private Die die1;
    private Die die2;

public Craps_callee() //
{
    die1 = new Die ();
    die2 = new Die ();

}

private void rollDice()
{
    die1.roll();
    die2.roll();
}


private int getSum()
{
    int sum = die1.getNumber()+die2.getNumber();
    return sum;
}

public void playRound()
{
    rollDice();
    int firstThrow = getSum();
    int secondThrow = getSum();

    //for (int i; i )


    if(firstThrow == 7 || firstThrow == 11) 
    {
        System.out.println("You rolled a " +firstThrow+ " You Win Congratulations!");
    }
    else if (firstThrow == 2 || firstThrow == 3 || firstThrow == 12)
    {
        System.out.println("You rolled a "+firstThrow+" You Lose! ");
    }
    else 
    {
     System.out.println("You rolled a: "+firstThrow);
     System.out.println(" !! Establish Point !!");
     System.out.println(" you need to roll another "+firstThrow+" to win before 7 is rolled");  

     do
     {
     rollDice();
     secondThrow = getSum();

     System.out.println("SeconndThrow is: "+secondThrow);
     System.out.println("FirstThrow is: "+firstThrow);
     if (secondThrow == firstThrow)   
     {
       System.out.println("You rolled a " +secondThrow+ " Twice. You Win Congratulations!");
     }
     else if (secondThrow == 7)
     {
       System.out.println("You rolled a 7 You Lose! ");
     }
     }
     while (secondThrow != firstThrow || secondThrow != 7);        

    }



} 
 public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String prompt_from_user;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Input the amount of "+scan);

    prompt_from_user = scan.nextLine();

    if (prompt_from_user == "YES" || prompt_from_user == "yes");
    {

    }
```

This is the part that's wrong

```
do
         {
         rollDice();
         secondThrow = getSum();

         System.out.println("SeconndThrow is: "+secondThrow);
         System.out.println("FirstThrow is: "+firstThrow);
         if (secondThrow == firstThrow)   
         {
           System.out.println("You rolled a " +secondThrow+ " Twice. You Win Congratulations!");
         }
         else if (secondThrow == 7)
         {
           System.out.println("You rolled a 7 You Lose! ");
         }
         }
         while (secondThrow != firstThrow || secondThrow != 7);
```

Comment: add a `break;` after you print out that you win

Comment: where exactly do i put it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: which is quicker, trying to put somewhere, or to post here and wait for a reply?

Answer (score 1):

> *I wanted to only iterate when the* > secondThrow is not the same as > > the firstThrow and not a number 7

Read the sentence and realise then that your condition should implement an AND instead of an OR